# What do you call a flexible diving platform?

Tags: word-request, transatlantic-differences

[image: diving platforms at a diving competition]

What do you call a flexible diving platform? I just realized this, but in international competition the diving platform isn't always elastic and flexible, but I doubt they are called a diving platform since they protrude out of the platform. You can see four of them in the lower platforms. What are they called?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are called *springboards* (although they are often just called *diving boards*):

> **springboard** noun [ C ]
>
> a board that can bend, helping people to jump higher when jumping or diving into a swimming pool or when doing gymnastics

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/springboard)

Answer (score 19):

In American English, these "flexible diving platforms" are "[diving boards](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/diving-board)".

A Bing image search shows that [diving boards](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=diving%20board) look like what the original poster had in mind.

If it is very clear from context that the object is used to dive into an artificial pool of water, the term can be shortened to "board".

The International Olympic Committee's website refers to these objects as "[springboards](https://www.olympic.org/diving-equipment-and-history)".

Comment: Surely the rigid ones are [_diving platforms_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_platform) whilst the flexible ones are [_springboards_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springboard). They are all classified as [_diving boards_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_board)

Comment: @PeterJennings -- My understanding of a "diving board" is consistent with Collins' "American English" definition: "a springboard projecting over a swimming pool, lake, etc., for use as a takeoff in diving". A "rigid platform" does not resemble a "board". A long-enough, thin-enough "board" of lumber is flexible. If your understanding is consistent with Collins' "British English" definition, please feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @Jasper Collins, Cambridge, and Oxford (British English) dictionaries for "diving board" say "a board". Collins Advanced British English dictionary says "a platform or springboard". Collins Advanced American English says "a springboard". The British English consensus seems to be that a diving board is not a spring board. "Springboard" is defined as "a *flexible* board" not "a board". There are certainly non-competition-standard swimming pools in the UK with non-flexible "boards" which could not reasonably be called "platforms".

Comment: @alephzero -- My interpretation of the Collins dictionary entry is that the meaning of "diving board" is different in British English than in American English.  I am not surprised that, as an American, my understanding of "diving board" matches the American English definition:  A springboard.  Whereas Peter Jennings' understanding of "diving board" matches the British English definition:  either a springboard or a rigid diving platform.  You, Peter Jennings, or another British English speaker might want to post an answer.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that springboard is used in the UK in casual conversation (especially by people who aren't specifically involved in the sport)? A very quick search shows that at least sometimes a "springboard" is marketed as a "diving board" without modifier in the UK (e.g., https://www.ukpoolstore.co.uk/acatalog/swimming-pool-diving-boards.html ). Just a guess, but probably because in many cases the only diving boards are springboards... Someone who is involved in the sport certainly knows the difference, but not someone who goes to their local pool to jump off the ___.

Comment: In the US, for recreational swimmers (not professionals), I can confirm this is just a "diving board".  Diving platforms don't exist outside of specialized professional pools, so since these are the only ones people normally see, there's no need to get detailed with "spring board".  It's just a diving board.  Tall diving boards springboards or platforms) can be referred to as "high dives".

Comment: @JPhi1618 Agreed. I'd wager most Americans are not familiar with, or at least wouldn't use, the term _springboard_ for this. It's definitely a diving board in everyday speech, and diving platforms are definitely _not_ diving boards.

Comment: In US English (at least as I understand it), only the narrow, light blue boards (two at lower left, two at center) would be called diving boards.  They're the only kind in common use.  The wider, darker blue ones would probably be called platforms, though I can't recall seeing ones like that.  (Not a competitive swimmer or diver, though.)  A diving board would have a good amount of spring to it, but a springboard (though quite similar) is used in gymnastics.

Answer (score 4):

Springboard is the term. When I used to swim and dive regularly, (in UK), the 'boards' were the solid platforms that had steps up to them - often at three different levels. Hence the 'top board'.

The springboard was a flexible board, often longer than the others, (its inboard end was further from the water), and sometimes adjustable in the free length over the water, to enable a variable amount of 'spring'.

Comment: Actually, what do you call the fixed ones, Tim ?!

Comment: @Fattie - boards, simply boards...

Comment: it's always great to see "actual experience" answers on these sites.